# Shutdown computer, how operating systems achieve it? (C Kernel development)

Tags: c, operating-system, kernel, system-shutdown

I've been developing an OS lately in C. But how can I shutdown the computer? By saying 'shutdown the computer', I mean a force shutdown.


How can I do that in C kernel development?

**Any help would be appreciated.**

Comment: I'd say a [duplicate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122557/how-does-the-system-shutdown-of-a-linux-kernel-work-internally)

Comment: @vtronko I am not talking about the linux kernel, I am talking about a kernel built from scratch

Comment: As there is no actual CPU command that shuts down the computer. The operating system effectively "simulates" a shutdown, by ending all processes and getting the CPU to a OS-specific routine that does nothing and also tries to consume minimum power. Then user after having computer turn blank, he pushes the power-off switch. So effectively it is a simulation not a real shutdown, real shutdown (unless CPU provides actual such command). Real shutdown happens by hardwarre switch powered off

Comment: Effectively a software (OS) shutdown is to have the computer do absolutely nothing.

Comment: [this](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/6780/its-now-safe-to-turn-off-your-computer) may provide some background

Comment: You should use the "Advanced Configuration and Power Interface" (ACPI) to do it. https://wiki.osdev.org/Shutdown

Comment: OK. Thanks so much to everyone for helping me

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface

Comment: and [here is a microsoft  pattent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US6209088B1/en) that describes os-controlled hibernation that later became the ACPI standard

Comment: [https://dortania.github.io/Getting-Started-With-ACPI/](https://dortania.github.io/Getting-Started-With-ACPI/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*To sum up all the comments in an answer so it stays:*

The modern way (circa 2020) to handle power management and shutdown is to use the [Advanced Configuration and Power Interface (ACPI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface), see for example [Getting Started With ACPI](https://dortania.github.io/Getting-Started-With-ACPI/) and [OS Shutdown](https://wiki.osdev.org/Shutdown).

> **History of ACPI**
>
> ACPI was developed through collaboration between Intel, Microsoft,
>   Toshiba, HP, and Phoenix in the mid-1990s. Before the development of
>   ACPI, operating systems (OS) primarily used BIOS (Basic Input/Output
>   System) interfaces for power management and device discovery and
>   configuration. This power management approach used the OS’s ability to
>   call the system BIOS natively for power management. The BIOS was also
>   used to discover system devices and load drivers based on probing
>   input/output (I/O) and attempting to match the correct driver to the
>   correct device (plug and play). The location of devices could also be
>   hard coded within the BIOS because the platform itself was
>   non-enumerable.These solutions were problematic in three key ways.
>   First, the behavior of OS applications could be negatively affected by
>   the BIOS-configured power management settings, causing systems to go
>   to sleep during presentations or other inconvenient times. Second, the
>   power management interface was proprietary on each system. This
>   required developers to learn how to configure power management for
>   each individual system. Finally, the default settings for various
>   devices could also conflict with each other, causing devices to crash,
>   behave erratically, or become undiscoverable.ACPI was developed to
>   solve these problems and others.
>
> **What is ACPI?**
>
> ACPI can first be understood as an architecture-independent power
>   management and configuration framework that forms a subsystem within
>   the host OS. This framework establishes a hardware register set to
>   define power states (sleep, hibernate, wake, etc). The hardware
>   register set can accommodate operations on dedicated hardware and
>   general purpose hardware.The primary intention of the standard ACPI
>   framework and the hardware register set is to enable power management
>   and system configuration without directly calling firmware natively
>   from the OS. ACPI serves as an interface layer between the system
>   firmware (BIOS) and the OS, as shown in Figure0-1 and Figure0-2, with
>   certain restrictions and rules.
>
> [image: ACPI overview]

*Source: [Advanced Configuration and Power Interface (ACPI) Specification, Version 6.3 January 2019](https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/ACPI_6_3_May16.pdf)*

[This answer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/6782) provides the historical background on the problem of OS controlling computer power and shutdown, and why it has taken so long to achieve some standard. Quoting:

> **Some history...**
>
> Before 1995 and the adoption of the ATX standard, the vast majority of
>   desktop PCs had power switches which were directly connected to the
>   power supply, and acted as mechanical switches only, interrupting the
>   electric circuit when opened. It was therefore impossible for software
>   to control the state of the power supply. But that wasn’t much of a
>   problem initially: when the IBM PC was designed, storage media
>   (including hard drives) had no caches, so when the hardware told the
>   operating system that a write was finished, it really was. Under DOS,
>   the kernel and shell worked together to ensure that when the DOS
>   prompt was displayed, all the buffers were flushed; when software
>   caches appeared, they adhered to this too (at least, the well-behaved
>   ones did). Users were taught to exit programs, wait for the prompt,
>   and wait for drive lights to switch off before powering the system
>   down. (They might also need to PARK the drive heads but that’s another
>   story.) Even with pre-95 versions Windows, users exited to DOS before
>   switching the system off.
>
> Windows 95 and other multi-tasking operating systems changed the
>   picture: they didn’t “exit to DOS” on shutdown (either because they
>   weren’t supposed to, or because there was no DOS to return to), so
>   users couldn’t wait for a prompt to appear before switching off. In
>   most truly multi-tasking systems there’s never really a quiescent
>   state where the system is safe to power off, in normal operation; so
>   most multi-tasking operating systems have a way for the user to say “I
>   want to power the system down, prepare to do so”, and the operating
>   system then needs to tell the user when it’s safe to power off. This
>   ensures that all applications have finished writing the user’s files
>   to disk, and that the system is in a consistent state (ignoring hard
>   drive caches here...).
>
> **Shutting down PCs**
>
> Two features brought system power under operating system control: APM
>   on the one hand, and ATX on the other. APM, which was designed for
>   laptops initially, provided mechanisms for software to request changes
>   in the system’s power state: fully on, in standby, suspended, or off.
>   ATX changed the physical connections in the system so that power
>   control became possible everywhere: it required that the power button
>   no longer be a switch directly connected to the power supply, but
>   instead that it be connected to the motherboard, and that the
>   motherboard control the power supply itself. The power supply was also
>   changed so that it would supply a small amount of current all the
>   time, allowing the system to be left in “soft off” status, i.e. with
>   enough capabilities to turn itself back on again when requested to do
>   so.
>
> You can see an example of the use of APM to power off a PC in
>   Shutdown, a small assembly-language program written for DOS. Operating
>   systems such as Windows 95 (with the APM drivers installed) would do
>   the same thing.
>
> It was quite exciting (to me anyway) to see APM and ATX roll out
>   progressively in the second half of the nineties, and see systems
>   suddenly acquire the ability to turn themselves off without human
>   intervention, and to turn themselves back on at the press of a key on
>   some systems. This was yet another sign of PCs “growing up” (“real”
>   computers, i.e. Unix workstations in my mind at the time, had had the
>   ability for a while, as had Macs).
>
> **Why did it take so long?**
>
> All this doesn’t address the actual question:
>
> > Was it really that hard to implement a self shut-off? What is the reason it took quite long for computers to feature this.
>
> If you design it in from the start, it’s not all that hard to
>   implement self shut-off, and many systems existed with this ability
>   quite a few years before the PC acquired it.
>
> [..]In the early nineties, surprising as it may seem now, there was a fair
>   amount of uncertainty as to what the computing future held. Apple was
>   making its comeback with cheaper Macs, workstation manufacturers were
>   releasing lower-priced systems (or rather, not-so-expensive systems),
>   a variety of operating systems and platforms were vying for attention
>   (Be, RiscPC...), IBM was still pushing OS/2 and Taligent, Microsoft
>   was pushing Windows NT, etc.
>
> Eventually an alliance of companies took it upon itself to “remedy”
>   this situation: Intel and Microsoft (referred to at the time as
>   Wintel). This started in the early nineties, but wasn’t a done deal
>   for quite a while; when ATX was published in 1995 (by Intel on its
>   own), pundits liked it but weren’t sure it would convince the
>   industry, although they were proved wrong fairly quickly. Windows 95
>   sealed the deal though and Intel and Microsoft became the definers of
>   the PC platform (with the PC System Design Guide in particular).

Here is [a Microsoft patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US6209088B1/en) from the 90's for software-controlled computer hibernation which is related to software-controlled power management.

Effectively, software-controlled shutdown is a kind of *simulation of shutdown*, as **real shutdown takes place when hardware power is actually switched off**. Soft shutdown effectively is to **make computer do absolutely nothing and consume as less power as possible**. So OS makes sure to **end all processes and make the CPU go to specific OS routines that simulate a shutdown** (note: this state usually cannot be reversed except by a hardware interrupt of restart). Whether the OS routines that make soft-shutdown use ACPI or some other method/interface to simulate is another issue.

[This post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122557/how-does-the-system-shutdown-of-a-linux-kernel-work-internally) describes, roughly in outline, the shutdown process of the linux kernel, to get an idea.

> [..]Anyways in there we have basically three functions that sketch the
>   process of shutting down the system
>
> ```
> void kernel_halt(void) // which ends with a system in halt state
> void kernel_power_off(void) // which ends with a system powered off
> void kernel_restart(char *cmd) // which ends the system to yet restart it
> ```
>
> Those functions are very brief and can be hence pasted here in
>   complete. Their code best shows what steps are taken on the way to
>   shutdown in the kernel. (the comments are by me and might not be 100%
>   ideal and correct, check yourself for being sure. It is simple a try.
>
> ```
> void kernel_halt(void)
> {
>     // 1st step does:
>     // a) call functions/callback registered to run at reboot/shutdown
>     // b) set system_sate to SYSTEM_HALT
>     // c) stop the userspacetool interaction
>     // d) call device_shutdown() function
>     kernel_shutdown_prepare(SYSTEM_HALT);
>
>     // 2nd step: I think this is mostly a necessity for multi-cpu systems
>     migrate_to_reboot_cpu();
>
>     // 3rd step:
>     // syscore_shutdown - Execute all the registered system core shutdown callbacks 
>     syscore_shutdown();
>
>     // 4th messages
>     pr_emerg("System halted\n");
>     kmsg_dump(KMSG_DUMP_HALT);
>
>     // 5th call arch specific cpu-halt-code
>     machine_halt();
> }
> ```